# How to go to previous activity through actionBar which is redirected from many activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have activities A,B,C and D. I have a menu in action bar in every activity. In C , I have a menu to redirect to B and D. In D, I have a menu to redirect to A,B and C, etc. So how can i go to previous activity clicking through actionBar when I am in B activity if it is from C or D. I need a help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you  Activity is in stack then  you can  use this

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityC.class);
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT)
startActivity(resultIntent);
```

Comment: Using FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT  you  call your  stack activity no need to add new activity

Comment: The code is working fine, but actually If I am in B activity which is redirected from D,it is not going while clicking through actionBar  to the D activity(previous activity).It is going to A which is my home activity. There is also a button to go to B in the home Activity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

**move to previous activity** ,

```
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back_dark);
        actionBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.name));

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

now to **move in anyother activity from current activit**y,

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```